# Add second trusted voice to Google Pixel

Tags: security, voice-recognition, 7.0-nougat, ok-google, google-pixel

Is it possible to add a second "trusted voice" to my Google Pixel so that a second person can say "OK Google" to unlock my phone? I would like to do this so that my phone can act like a substitute for Google Home when I'm at home--in order to enable my partner to unlock through "OK Google", but still restrict it to our two voices only.

If it isn't possible to do through a single user, is it possible that setting up a second user will allow this? I'm not familiar with how switching between users works on Android yet.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with a single user. As you predicted, however, it is indeed possible to set up with a second user, as each user is set up almost like its own phone. Just add a new user, set it up, and then set up the voice as you would normally.

Good luck!